# how to associate several file types with an application (kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, file-association

I want to associate several file type to an application

example:

- *.mp3*, *.ogg*, *.avi*, *.mpg*, ... with VLC
- *.txt*, *.js*, *.css*, *.py*, ... with VSCode
- *.jpg*, *.png*, *.webp*, ... with Gwenview

I currently have to :

1. open a directory containing a *mp3* file
2. right click on the file
3. open with >
4. other application...
5. search for *VLC* in the list
6. don't forget to check "always use this app to open .mp3 files"
7. OK

and repeat for each file type...

I search a way to set association of several file types in one command.

like:

```bash
associate --ext 'mp3 ogg avi mpg' --app vlc
```